# objC bitwise add

Tags: objective-c, bitwise-and

Where

```
val = 3325
val &= 65535;


[rtnData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", val] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I am expecting <30434644> 0CFD

but getting <636664> cfd

So either 3325 is not the correct beginning val (but I have derived it from 2 different functions) or the bitwise addition is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is bitwise "and", not bitwise-addition.

And the code is wrong because you have used the wrong format. Use `@"%04X"` instead of `@"%x"`. (where **0** = pad with 0 if not long enough, **4** = at least 4 characters, **X** = upper case hexadecimal)

Comment: Thanks the %04X did the trick - slap forehead - I recognized the problems, but overlooked the formatting.